# IndexOf a whole Array and alert names

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, indexof

I am trying to write the following javascript in a html file.

Create an array containing the names of 10 sports teams.

Then loop through the array using a "for loop". If a team name contains the letters "an", then alert the team's name. I would like to use the "indexOf" function to determine whether "an" is contained in the team name.

This is how far I got:

```
    // index:                                   
    var NHL = new Array("New Jersey Devils", "New York Islanders", 
                       "New York Rangers", "Philadelphia Flyers", 
                       "Pittsburgh Penguins", "Boston Bruins", 
                       "Buffalo Sabres", "Montreal Canadiens" , 
                       "Ottawa Senators", "Toronto Maple Leafs");

    for( i=0 , i<NHL.indexOf("an") , i++ ){
      if(NHL.indexOf == "an"){
          alert(indexOf)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf(str)` will return non-negative index. It will return -1 if the substring is not present in it, else it will return the first occurence of that str.

```
var NHL = new Array("New Jersey Devils", "New York Islanders", 
          "New York Rangers", "Philadelphia Flyers", "Pittsburgh Penguins", 
          "Boston Bruins", "Buffalo Sabres", "Montreal Canadiens" , 
          "Ottawa Senators", "Toronto Maple Leafs"); 

for(i=0; i<NHL.length; i++)
{
    if(NHL[i].indexOf("an") !== -1)
        alert(NHL[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code works perfect. I see now where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
var NHL = new Array("New Jersey Devils", "New York Islanders", "New York Rangers", "Philadelphia Flyers", "Pittsburgh Penguins", "Boston Bruins", "Buffalo Sabres", "Montreal Canadiens" , "Ottawa Senators", "Toronto Maple Leafs");

for(var i=0, len=NHL.length; i<len; i++ ){
  var name=NHL[i];
  if(name.indexOf("an")>-1){
      alert(name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var NHL = new Array("New Jersey Devils", "New York Islanders", 
"New York Rangers", "Philadelphia Flyers", "Pittsburgh Penguins", 
"Boston Bruins", "Buffalo Sabres", "Montreal Canadiens" , 
"Ottawa Senators", "Toronto Maple Leafs"); 

/** 
 * Iterate through each array element,
 * Check against 'an', indexOf returns -1
 * if no match found.
**/
for( var i=0 ; i < NHL.length; i++ ) {
     if ( NHL[i].indexOf("an") !== -1 ) 
            alert( "This " + NHL[i] + " Contains 'an' at array index: " + i );
}
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/HqXSs/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code also worked great. Little different approach, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var NHL = new Array("New Jersey Devils", "New York Islanders", "New York Rangers", "Philadelphia Flyers", "Pittsburgh Penguins", "Boston Bruins", "Buffalo Sabres", "Montreal Canadiens" , "Ottawa Senators", "Toronto Maple Leafs");

for (var i=0; i<NHL.length; i++){
    if(NHL[i].indexOf("an") !== -1){
        alert(NHL[i]);
    }
}
```